# Recognizing license plate characters using template characters in Python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, character, detection, image-recognition

For a university project I have to recognize characters from a license plate. I have to do this using python 3. I am not allowed to use OCR functions or use functions that use deep learning or neural networks. I have reached the point where I am able to segment the characters from a license plate and transform them to a uniform format. A few examples of segmented characters are here.
[image: Segmented Characters]

The format of the segmented characters is very dependent on the input. However, I can easily convert this to uniform dimensions using opencv. Additionally, I have a set of template characters and numbers that I can use to predict what character / number it is.

[image: Same Size Numbers]

[image: Same Size Letters]

I therefore need a metric to express the similarity between the segmented character and the reference image. In this way, I can say that the reference image with the highest similarity score matches the segmented character. I have tried the following ways to compute the similarity.

For these operations I have made sure that the reference characters and the segmented characters have the same dimensions.

- A bitwise XOR-operator
- Inverting the reference characters and comparing them pixel by pixel. If a pixel matches increment the similarity score, if a pixel does not match decrement the similarity score.
- hash both the segmented character and the reference character using 'imagehash'. Consequently comparing the hashes and see which ones are most similar.

None of these methods succeed to give me an accurate prediction for all characters. Most characters are usually correctly predicted. However, the program confuses characters like 8-B, D-0, 7-Z, P-R consistently.

Does anybody have an idea how to predict the segmented characters? I.e. defining a better similarity score.

Edit: Unfortunately, cv2.matchTemplate and cv2.matchShapes are not allowed for this assignment...

Comment: see template matching at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be But doing this does not work if the template and characters are rotated or scaled differently. Perhaps you want shape matching. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaadc90cb16e2362c9bd6e7363e6e4c317

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general procedure for comparing two images consists in the extraction of features from the two images and their subsequent comparison. What you are actually doing in the first two methods is considering the value of every pixel as a feature. The similarity measure is therefore a distance-computation on a space of very high dimension. This methods are, however, subject to noise and this requires very big datasets in order not to obtain acceptable results.

For this reason, usually one attempts to reduce the space dimensionality. I'm not familiar with the third method, but it seems to go in this direction.

A way to reduce the space dimensionality consists in defining some custom features meaningful for the problem you are facing.

A possibility for the character classification problem could be to define features that measure the response of the input image on strategic subshapes of the characters (an upper horizontal line, a lower one, a circle in the upper part of the image, a diagonal line, etc.).
You could define a minimal set of shapes that, combined together, can generate every character. Then you should retrieve one feature for each shape, by measuring the response (*i.e.*, integrating the signal of the input image inside the shape) of the original image on that particular shape. Finally, you should determine the class which the image belongs to by taking the nearest reference point in this, smaller, space of the features.